# How many property can regular google analytics can accommodate as well as the premium Google Analytics?

Tags: analytics

I have 55 domains that I want to track in one Google Analytics account but based on my research regular Google Analytics account can only accommodate 50 property. Right? What i want here is I want to upgrade, anyone who has an idea on how many property can premium Google Analytics can accommodate? Any thoughts guys?

Answer (score 0):

I think the limits are based on hits, rather than properties. However, I do not think you can associate properties with domains. Normally Google Analytics tracks one domain, and supports cross domain tracking under certain conditions.
You can read more about cross domain tracking here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite
You can read about the comparison between Google free and paid here: https://www.google.com/analytics/analytics/compare/
Hope this helps,
Regards